# The filter does not return anything even after match in Javascript

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

so I am trying use this Filter in one of my functions but the filter return empty array even though there are few matches .

code

```
filteredCardList: function () {

  if (this.monthFilter.length > 0) {
    return this.cardList.filter((card) => {
      this.monthFilter.forEach(function (val) {
        if (val.toString() == card.months) {
          console.log('Matched')
          return true;
        } else {
          console.log('NoMatch')
          return false;
        }
      });
    })
  } else {
    return this.cardList
  }
}
```

Any ideas , most welcome

thanks

Comment: Where is this defined? Is it a computed property? FYI, Vue2 does not have *filters*

Comment: Also, what is `monthFilter`? Sometimes it looks like it should be a string an other times you're treating it like an array

Comment: @Phil let me clean the code sorry , I got your point

Comment: @Phil yes its a computed property , but filters are in core javascript , Can't I use it in Vue2 ? monthFilter is an array

Comment: Yes, you can use `Array.prototype.filter`. I just wasn't sure if you were referring to [Vue 1 filters](http://011.vuejs.org/api/filters.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, assuming `monthFilter` is an array and you want to filter `cardList` by the values inside using an *any* sort of match, try using [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?v=control)

```
filteredCardList: function () {
  if (this.monthFilter.length > 0) {
    return this.cardList.filter(card => {
      return this.monthFilter.some(val => {
        return val.toString() == card.months
      })
    })
  } else {
    return this.cardList
  }
}
```

Your problem was that your `return true` / `return false` was simply returning from the `forEach` callback and nothing was returned in the `filter` callback.

Comment: let me try this , also I tried creating a fiddle in javascript only https://jsfiddle.net/1nvfvu95/

Comment: its not working as expected , so when I i have one element in the `monthsFilter` array say 12 , that time it worked fine , then I updated my array with `12 , 24` , I console logged that inside your function and I see , two set of array 1 , with 12 and another iwth 12,24, but when i  checked returned cardList it still had only data with month as 12

Comment: @Vikram can you update your JSFiddle? I'm not seeing any problems with the code in my answer

Comment: I tried your code on my fiddle , apparantly it works fine , I think something I am doing wrong in my Vue instance sorry my bad I will accept your answer  https://jsfiddle.net/1nvfvu95/1/